# What is the Streaming Decryption setting in Google Drive?

Tags: encryption, google-drive

I notice a "Streaming Decryption" option under Encryption Settings. For me, it was not selected by default. The description under this setting is a little unclear:

> Decrypt documents into a stream incrementally.

So my question is what does this mean and what does it do? Does it mean that a given document is only partially decrypted (if there is such a thing) while it is open? Should the average user pay any attention to this setting? I found [this](http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-57420195-285/how-to-use-google-drive-on-android/) HowTo on CNET but it does not explain the setting.

*I don't recall whether this was a setting under the former (i.e. pre-Drive) Google Docs app.*

Comment: It sounds like only the portion visible on-screen is decrypted, possibly to limit damage if the unencrypted data is intercepted or recovered?

Comment: That sounds reasonable. It seems a side effect of that could be a reduction in the amount of data being transferred.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Goggle Drive gives you some security options regarding your documents:

- You can choose to encrypt all offline documents (that is, documents
  stored on your device);
- And can also choose to decrypt documents incrementally as they are
  streamed to your phone, by selecting the `Streaming Decryption`, thus having just a small portion of the document decrypted when accessing it. Kinda like watching a compressed video.

Sadly enough couldn't find any official documentation to support my answer on Google, but here's some relevant links:

[Access and Edit Files with Google Drive](http://android.appstorm.net/reviews/internet-reviews/access-and-edit-files-with-google-drive/)

[Google Drive - View files offline in the Google Drive Android app](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2440137&topic=1361437&ctx=topic)

Answer (score 0):

What this means is that Google decrypts as it streams so that if a file is cut off from streaming midway through, there is still a secure decrypted part remaining thus limiting the damage to the file if it is intercepted.
This Guy works For Google so i think he know whats he saying (GApps)/
Websites used:
http://www.quora.com/Google-Drive/What-does-Settings-Streaming-decryption-do-for-the-Google-Drive-Android-app